# .NET Framework 4 Library with .NET Core 2.2 Project

Tags: c#, dll, .net-core

So I have an existing .NET Framework 4 DLL that I would like to reference from a new .NET Core 2.2 application. Is this possible?

I have added the DLL as an assembly in the .NET Core project. It compiles fine, but when I run the project I'm getting this error:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0...".

Wondering if I need to try to convert the .NET Framework DLL to .NET Standard?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compatibility of dynamically loaded assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59444690/compatibility-of-dynamically-loaded-assemblies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wondering if I need to try to convert the .NET Framework DLL to .NET Standard?

That is exactly what you want to do.  Since .Net proper and .Net core are "implementation" frameworks they cannot reference each other.  However, .Net standard is more of an "interface" so it can be referenced from both .Net proper and .Net core.

The version of .Net standard is going to depend on which framework version you are targeting.  The lowest common denominator should win.

Have a look at [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem some time ago. I had to use .NET 4.0 because of compatibility with Windows XP.

.NET Core 2.2 requires at least .NET 4.5.

Solution is to upgrade to .NET 4.5 or above or to leave concept with .NET Core 2.2 inside .NET 4.0 project