# Referencing a .Net Core 3.1 project from a .Net Standard Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-core, .net-standard

So I have a `.NET Core 3.1` project. I am trying to create a unit testing project to go along with it. I have created a `.NET Standard 2.1 Class Library` for this purpose. I'm then trying to add a reference to the main project, in order to be able to reference code from there. This isn't working, as I get the following compilation errors:

> '..\MyProj\MyProj.csproj' targets 'netcoreapp3.1'. It cannot be
>   referenced by a project that targets '.NETStandard,Version=v2.1'.
>   Project MyProj is not compatible with netstandard2.1
>   (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1). Project MyProj supports: netcoreapp3.1
>   (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)    Test (test\Test)

So this does make sense to me, as I understand why `.NET Core` wouldn't be able to reference a `.NET Standard` project.
 But then how can I create a Unit Testing project? Is it possible to create a `.NET Core 3.1 Class Library`? From everything I have read, it seems like that doesn't exist.

How can I set up a unit test project that references the main project?

Comment: You should not do that. Please check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59444690/compatibility-of-dynamically-loaded-assemblies/59445495#59445495

Comment: I don't have any issue creating a .NET Core 3.1 Class library. What problem are you running into?

Comment: @JonathonChase - I do not have any option to create a .NET Core 3.1 class library, only a .NET standard one.

Comment: @panoskarajohn - yes, I am aware of why it should not be possible. However, I do not then have a solution of how to set up a unit testing project.

Comment: @Sean You should be able to create a new `.NET Core Class Library`. Also there are already visual studio templates.

Comment: @panoskarajohn tutorials that come up when googling "How to create a .NET Core Class Library" (e.g. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/building-a-net-core-class-library/) show the creation of a .NET Standard Class Library and seem to equate the two terms.

Comment: @Sean please check the link i have sent you. Standard is an interface between the two `.net core & .net framework`. Yes it is in general a good idea to have a `.net standard` library.But unit tests projects are a different case. They should be framework specific.

Comment: @panoskarajohn hmmm so I can find tutorials like this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dotnet_core/dotnet_core_create_testing_project.htm that appear to show that there should be an option in project creation for a .NET Core Class Library. However I don't have that option in my project templates, which is super weird!

Comment: @Josh thanks Josh though as I mention I understand completely why I cannot reference in this way, I just don't have a better solution to do what I need to do

Comment: @Sean This is a different question probably sth wrong with your installation. You should be able.

Comment: @Sean as I said, try re-installing the Core SDK.

Answer (score 4):

.NET Standard was created as an interface for different .NET implementations. For example, this allows you to share code between .NET Core and the full .NET framework. I would create your library as a .NET Standard 2.0 project and then you can reference it in your .NET Core 3.1 application and your unit testing project.

I only suggest .NET Standard as it is generally more portable than .NET Framework or .NET Core libraries. You'd be able to target more platforms such as Xamarin, desktop, or web with .NET Standard.

Comment: Yes, but what should the unit testing project be? Tutorials I have found say that the unit testing project should be a .NET Standard Class Library, and that does work fine if I don't need to reference the main project.

Comment: @Sean Test projects should be test projects. They have their own template. I don't know what tutorials you're looking at but you should find different ones. They are either outdated or just wrong to begin with.

Comment: @Sean, first you need to decide if you're using NUnit, xUnit, or MSTest as your testing framework. Then you can create a .NET Core based test project with your specific testing suite. You'll be able to reference .NET Standard 2.1 libraries from .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: I only suggest .NET Standard as it is generally more portable than .NET Framework or .NET Core libraries. You'd be able to target more platforms such as Xamarin, desktop, or web with .NET Standard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use .Net Core 3.1 in your project, not NetStandard. I use it this way and there is no troubles. I guess you don't really need your unit testing to be portable?